# PHP: large amount of requests with file_get_contents

Tags: php, mysql, api, file-get-contents

I currently have a db table filled with organisation numbers [1,002 million rows].

Now, what im trying to do is fetch the phone number of the organisation from a remote website API. I've got this working, but just after 30-50 or so requests to the API, i dont see any new changes to the table im inserting the phone numbers into. I've still got 1 million++ rows to fetch the phone number from, but i cant seem to get further than a small amount of rows.

Thanks in advance for the help.

I dont know if this is gonna help, but here is the code im using to do this.

```
// Remove timeout limit
// This is going to take alot of time!
set_time_limit(0); 

// Initialize...
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/core/Init.php';

// Profiles
$url = 'http://finnrett.no/API/business/get/quickresults?q=';
$profile_url = 'http://finnrett.no/API/business/get/profile?id=';

// Select names
$sql = 'SELECT organisasjonsnummer FROM brreg  ORDER BY id LIMIT 10000';
$result = $Dbh -> query($sql, []);

// Each name
foreach ($result as $orgnr) {

    // Pre for output explananation
    echo'<pre>';

    // Grab json from quick results url
    $bedrift = json_decode(file_get_contents($url.$orgnr['organisasjonsnummer']));
    $ID = get_object_vars($bedrift[0])['ID'];

    $profile = json_decode(file_get_contents($profile_url.$ID));
    $CONTACT = get_object_vars($profile);
    $number = $CONTACT['contact'] ? $CONTACT['contact']: '0';

    $sql = 'INSERT INTO profiles (orgnr, telefon) VALUES (:orgnr, :telefon)';
    $args = ['orgnr' => $orgnr['organisasjonsnummer'], 'telefon' => $number];
    if (!$Dbh -> query($sql, $args)) {
        echo 'Sjekk opp org: ' . $orgnr['organisasjonsnummer'] . ' fordi her skjedde det noe galt.';
    }


}
```

Looks like i solved it by choosing curl instead of file_get_contents.

Comment: It's just a delay problem? You can fetch all records but it just starts to respond after requesting 30~50 records?

Comment: No. It doesnt continue fetching anything after 30-50 records. 
I got the numbers on the 30-50, but after that, nothing at all.

Comment: What API is you using? just a wild guess but maybe it's a mechanism to avoid DoS, anyway you can refer to the API documentation os call support.

Comment: http://finnrett.no/API/business/get/profile?id=##
http://finnrett.no/API/business/get/quickresults?q=##

Theese API's. Its not documentation on them though. But you might be right. It might be some sort of protection.

Comment: @Kaizokupuffball instead of editing your question with your solution, make an answer of it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by switching to [`curl`](http://php.net/curl) instead of [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/file_get_contents)